# Removing event data of a user without deleting the user in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to remove event data of a user without deleting the user?

I know there is filter to filter out data in the custom report but I would like to get rid of the data accidentally sent as the event label.

Deleting the user would be the last resort as it will also affect the analysis of other events triggered by those users.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No you can only delete data on the user/client level.